SonarCloud Github Actions MSBuild failing with 'system cannot find the file specified.'
I'm trying to use SonarCloud's Github Actions within a CI to build and test a Windows based C++ application. The issue I'm facing is that regardless of how I update the Run build wrapper step, the job failed with the below error:
[SONARSOURCE BUILD-WRAPPER] failed to execute msbuild.exe .\MySolution.sln /t:Rebuild: The system cannot find the file specified.

My existing config is below. I have listed the directly using gci and ls in the job and confirmed the file is present. I have changed into the correct directory, renamed files, used relative paths and created ${{ env.BUILD_WRAPPER_OUT_DIR }}, just in case. Every time I end up with the same error.
Some examples of what I've tried:
build-wrapper-win-x86-64 --out-dir ${{ env.BUILD_WRAPPER_OUT_DIR }} msbuild.exe MySolution.sln 
build-wrapper-win-x86-64 --out-dir ${{ env.BUILD_WRAPPER_OUT_DIR }} msbuild .\MySolution.sln 
build-wrapper-win-x86-64 --out-dir ${{ env.BUILD_WRAPPER_OUT_DIR }} MSBuild.exe .\MySolution.sln 

I assumed msbuild was looking for the .sln file, but that doesn't seem correct. It's just not clear what file isn't being found and causing the subsequent error. Any ideas for corrections much appreciated!
name: SonarCloud
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build and analyze
    runs-on: windows-latest
    env:
      BUILD_WRAPPER_OUT_DIR: build_wrapper_output_directory # Directory where build-wrapper output will be placed
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0  # Shallow clones should be disabled for a better relevancy of analysis
      - name: Install sonar-scanner and build-wrapper
        uses: SonarSource/sonarcloud-github-c-cpp@v3
      - name: Run build-wrapper
        run: |
          build-wrapper-win-x86-64 --out-dir ${{ env.BUILD_WRAPPER_OUT_DIR }} msbuild .\MySolution.sln /t:Rebuild
      - name: Run sonar-scanner
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          sonar-scanner --define sonar.cfamily.compile-commands="${{ env.BUILD_WRAPPER_OUT_DIR }}/compile_commands.json"

Job logs
Run build-wrapper-win-x86-64 --out-dir build_wrapper_output_directory msbuild.exe .\MySolution.sln /t:Rebuild
  build-wrapper-win-x86-64 --out-dir build_wrapper_output_directory msbuild.exe .\MySolution.sln /t:Rebuild
  shell: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
  env:
    BUILD_WRAPPER_OUT_DIR: build_wrapper_output_directory
    SONAR_HOST_URL: https://sonarcloud.io
  
[SONARSOURCE BUILD-WRAPPER] failed to execute msbuild .\MySolution.sln /t:Rebuild: The system cannot find the file specified.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.


You likely misunderstand ... seems that system fails with error that it does not find msbuild, not msbuild fails with error that it does not find dimly specified file.
